# Onset of turbulence

Tags: fluid-dynamics, turbulence

Does every fluid undergo a transition in the presence of disturbances? Even if we could isolate the disturbances entering the boundary will the fluid still undergo transition and become turbulent after a certain period. I have studied stability theory but it conjectures that only the stochastic effects of external disturbances or the receptivity of the boundary layer and it gives a stochastic answer to the prediction of the transition layer. Basically, will the fluid undergo a transition even in zero gravity?

Comment: Whether flow in a pipe becomes turbulent or not depends on Reynolds number, and does not involve gravity. There are flows which are unstable to infinitesimal disturbances and those which are not. Flows in the latter category can be prevented from becoming turbulent if sufficient care is taken to isolate disturbances (eg. flow in a pipe).